# How to define and use bean for eclipselink persistence?

Tags: spring, persistence, vaadin

I am developing an application which uses the vaadin framework. I used [Vaadin-AppFoundation](http://code.google.com/p/vaadin-appfoundation/) library for database access, that uses persistence.xml. How to define a bean using springframework for this persistence context and how to use it?

Please, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking but did you check the [Persistence](http://code.google.com/p/vaadin-appfoundation/wiki/Persistence) wiki page of the link you posted?

If you're looking for a more general introduction to JPA, maybe have a look at the [Introduction to the Java Persistence API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) in the Java EE tutorials.

If this doesn't help, can you clarify the question?

Comment: Persistence's wiki provides the implementation steps.

Comment: But, I want to know how to define a bean for that persistence context. Lets consider the JNDI context, we define the context for that in web.xml using <resource-ref> then straightway we can define that resource reference inside the app-context.xml. Something like that. I hope you are clear with my question now.